# Reverse/Blow out a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working with data that is grouped by item number with counts. Each record with a `count > 2` needs to be blown out into individual records and compared at that level to a different set of data.

The data looks like this (It is stuck in this format. This is the only way the customer can send it.):

```
OwnerNumber ItemCode    ItemNumber  CountOfItems
1234    Item1   Item1-001   3
1234    Item1   Item1-002   1
1234    Item1   Item1-003   2
1234    Item2   Item2-001   1
```

And I need the data formatted like this (dynamically without hardcoding for value of CountOfItems):

```
OwnerNumber ItemCode    ItemNumber  
1234    Item1   Item1-001
1234    Item1   Item1-001
1234    Item1   Item1-001
1234    Item1   Item1-002
1234    Item1   Item1-003
1234    Item1   Item1-003
1234    Item2   Item2-001
```

For some reason I just can't wrap my head around a clean way to do this (or any way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage with a Common Table Expression

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT OwnerNumber,ItemCode,ItemNumber,CountOfItems FROM table

    UNION ALL SELECT OwnerNumber,ItemCode,ItemNumber,CountOfItems-1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CountOfItems >= 2
)
SELECT OwnerNumber,ItemCode,ItemNumber
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ItemNumber
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Edit:**

Added `MAXRECURSION` to handle situations where CountOfItems exceeds default max recursions as pointed out by Dev_etter

Comment: Thank you.  Some minor nit-picking:  It's best to _always_ specify which columns are being `SELECT`ed, especially if the ordering in the table may change.  The same reasoning applies to the definition of CTE columns.

Comment: True, I agree. I edited it. But why caring about CTE definition columns? They will be indirectly defined from the order I choose in the `SELECT`clause?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I remember reading about recursive CTE's but have yet to use one. I guess I just didn't know how the right time to use one.

Comment: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. So...what happens if I have to process over 600k records?

Comment: I got it. Added OPTION(MAXRECURSION,0) to the end of the last SELECT statement.

Comment: Hmm, it's not as necessary, perhaps; I guess I just like to do it for completionism's sake.  Although, occasionally you need a function or constant in the initial `SELECT`, which means you need a column alias, at minimum...

Comment: @dev_etter: Ah, good point! Yes, you need to set MAXRECURSIONS to either 0 or to the maximum value that CountofItems might have. How many records doesn't affect the number of recursions made in this case.

Comment: @X-Zero: Yes, I use column alias in case of anonymous fields. But I guess it is a matter of taste, completion or less typing; I normally go to towards the Golang approach - I prefer to type less :)

Comment: @ANisus, Is it bad practice to just set it to 0? Or should I take the time to seek out the max for CountOfItems and use it here?

Comment: @dev_etter: Setting it to 0 is a risk of course since it makes it possible to create an eternal loop. But you are not allowed to use a variable with MAXRECURSION ( `OPTION (MAXRECURSION @count)` ). Depending on your project, if you can cap it, it would be good. Set it to 4000 or something which should normally never occur.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.... I think I like recursive CTEs for this:

```
WITH Data (OwnerNumber, ItemCode, ItemNumber, CountOfItems) as (
           SELECT OwnerNumber, ItemCode, ItemNumber, CountOfItems
           FROM OriginalTable
           UNION ALL
           SELECT OwnerNumber, ItemCode, ItemNumber, CountOfItems - 1
           FROM Data
           WHERE CountOfItems > 1)
SELECT OwnerNumber, ItemCode, ItemNumber
FROM Data
ORDER BY OwnerNumber, ItemCode, ItemNumber
```

Comment: I like the way you are thinking ;) . Near identical!

Comment: I gave the answer to ANisus only because he beat you by one minute. Both are the same approach and get me the right results. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid recursion with the query below, and I think will be more efficient. Here, the table N is any table with at least as many rows as the largest CountOfItems value.

This is a rare example of a query where TOP without ORDER BY is not a bad idea.

```
select
  OwnerNumber,
  ItemCode,
  ItemNumber
from t
cross apply (
  select top (CountOfItems) null
  from N
 ) as N(c)
```

Comment: +1 For a fun and creative solution. I've never seen such a way to use a variable value for TOP, playing with a dummy table. But whether it is more efficient or not I have no idea myself.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. I tested this one though and at 4 and a half minutes it had only blown out about half of the results. The other queries complete in a little over 4 minutes. FYI I'm working with over 600k grouped records that result in over 4 million blown out records.