# Select Rows from a Column value in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a situation to make a sql query to get no of rows from column value. Consider my example,

**Example**

```
Id             No              Copies

1              001               2
2              002               3
3              003               1
```

**Expected query result**

```
Id             No              Copy

1              001               1
1              001               1
2              002               1
2              002               1
2              002               1
3              003               1
```

I have no idea about the query logic in sql server. Any help to this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129616/reverse-blow-out-a-group-by

Looks to be what you're after